# Error compiling program - Maths library failure?

Tags: compiling, make, ubuntu-make

I have Ubuntu server (no GIU) version Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and an trying to install a program 'parsefsh-1.0-g231'.

I have downloaded the file and de-compressed it fine, now I need to compile it, so have tried 'make' but get the following error..

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_VLOG   -c -o projection.o projection.c
gcc -lm  parsefsh.o fshfunc.o projection.o   -o parsefsh
projection.o: In function `init_ellipsoid':
/home/ian/parsefshsrc/parsefsh-1.0-g231/projection.c:51: undefined reference to `pow'
/home/ian/parsefshsrc/parsefsh-1.0-g231/projection.c:51: undefined reference to `sqrt'
projection.o: In function `phi_rev_merc':
/home/ian/parsefshsrc/parsefsh-1.0-g231/projection.c:66: undefined reference to `sin'
/home/ian/parsefshsrc/parsefsh-1.0-g231/projection.c:67: undefined reference to `exp'
projection.o: In function `northing':
/home/ian/parsefshsrc/parsefsh-1.0-g231/projection.c:95: undefined reference to `tan'
/home/ian/parsefshsrc/parsefsh-1.0-g231/projection.c:95: undefined reference to `sin'
projection.o: In function `coord_diff':
/home/ian/parsefshsrc/parsefsh-1.0-g231/projection.c:111: undefined reference to `cos'
/home/ian/parsefshsrc/parsefsh-1.0-g231/projection.c:113: undefined reference to `atan2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'parsefsh' failed
make: *** [parsefsh] Error 1
```

(there were more lines with different maths functions but I've removed them to shorten this message)

It looks to my No0b eyes an issue with the maths functions, I've done some Internet searching and a recommendation was found to try the following...

```
gcc projection.c -o projection.o -lm
```

but this gives me an error

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now I'm stuck and can't really find any other answers on the Internet, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

Your research has led you along the right lines.

Examination of the software's Makefile shows that the rules for creating target `parsefish` are

```
parsefsh: parsefsh.o fshfunc.o projection.o

parsefsh.o: parsefsh.c fshfunc.h

fshfunc.o: fshfunc.c fshfunc.h

projection.o: projection.c projection.h
```

Because there are no explicit *actions* for these rules, GNU Make uses its [built-in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html). For the compile phase (`.c` to `.o`) that's

```
$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c
```

which works fine, given the Makefile's definitions

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -g -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_VLOG
```

however in the link phase, the rule is of the form

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
```

Note that `$(LDFLAGS)` comes **before** the object code file `n.o`, whereas `$(LOADLIBES)` and `$(LDLIBS)` come after. In the Makefile, only `LDFLAGS` is defined:

```
LDFLAGS = -lm
```

which puts `-lm` in the wrong place (references are resolved from left to right).

The simplest solution is simply to change `LDFLAGS = -lm` to `LDLIBS = -lm`.

Comment: Wowser that works! thanks ever so much!
I was about to start writing my own program in Python or VB to do the same job - you have saved me 10's of hours of work - possibly 100's! I read through your explanation and managed to follow it most of the way, I am curious however - since the program is a few years old and there are quite a few versions of it, I am surprised that there is so little noise about the compile fail on the Internet, it makes me think it used to compile fine but now does not - would there be a change in the compiling process in the past couple of years that might cause this?